# Trying to find a flexible function that models non-exponential decay and does not converge to zero

Tags: functions, hyperbolic-functions, nonlinear-dynamics

I use non-linear regression to model decay in a population, but I have not been able to find a good functional form form. Assume:

- The decay is not exponential (not a constant percentage each time unit; Usually steeper initially than an exponential function, then flatter)
- The function should have a limit that is above zero. Infinite time does not imply complete decay. At some point the decay stops and the line is flat.
- At t=0, the function should be 1

I tried a function of the following form, used in hyperbolic discounting:
y=b/(1 + c t)

where t is time, and b and c are parameters that are estimated based on the observed points, but this function converges to zero and adding a constant parameter means that it is no longer one at t=0.

Any suggestions for functions that could fit would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can simply modify your function to get $\displaystyle y = a + \frac{1-a}{1 + ct}$, where $0<a<1$ is the desired limit as $t\to \infty$.

Comment: You say "at some point the decay stops and the line is flat". Does this mean that you actually want the function to reach a minimum value?

Comment: $y=\dfrac{1-k}{(1+ct)^d} +k$ might meet your needs; your $b$ needs to be $1$ if you want $y(0)=1$.  You have flexibility on the limit $k$, the scale with $c$ and then the shape with $d$

Comment: Ben Grossman: Thank you for the suggetion. Yes, a want it to reach a minimum value, but this could differ from case to case  (a parameter to be estimated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possibility: consider
$$
y = 
\begin{cases}
b + (1-b)\exp(a/T)\exp\left(\frac{a}{t - T}\right) & t < T\\
b & t\geq T
\end{cases}
$$
Here, $b$ is the desired minimum value, $T$ is the time at which $y$ reaches its minimum, and $a$ determines the rate of decrease (larger $a$ means a faster decrease). Per my discussion in the second part of my answer, I recommend taking $a > 2T$.

The function is designed so that the transition from $t < T$ to $t \geq T$ is smooth. Here's a graph of the resulting curve for $b = 0.1, T=1,$ and several values of $a$.

[image]

---

As an aside, you can see from the $a=1$ graph that for values of $a$ that are too small, the function noticeably fails to be convex, which may be undesirable. Here's a calculation to determine for which values of $a$ that occurs.

We find that the second derivative of $y = \exp\left(\frac{a}{t - T}\right)$ is given by
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = \frac{a e^{\frac{a}{t - T}}}{\left(t - T\right)^{4}} \left(a + 2 (t - T)\right),
$$
which means that an inflection point occurs where
$$
a + 2(t - T) = 0 \implies t = T - \frac a2.
$$
If we take $a > 2T$, then we guarantee that this inflection point does not occur within the range $0 \leq t \leq T$.